# Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I am trying to create a line graph and scatter plot on the same figure. There should be two lines and two scatterplots.

```
datamax['datamax'] = datamax2015['Data_Value']
datamin['datamin'] = datamin2015['Data_Value']

ax = plt.gca()
datamax.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value',color='red',ax=ax)
datamin.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value', color='blue',ax=ax)
datamax.plot(kind='scatter',x='Date',y='breakup',color='red',ax=ax)
datamin.plot(kind='scatter',x='Date',y='breakdown', color='blue',ax=ax)

plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees C)",color='navy')
plt.xlabel("Date",color='navy',labelpad=15)
plt.title('Record high and low temperatures by day (2005-2014)', alpha=1.0,color='brown',y=1.08)
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.35),
          fancybox=False,labels=['Record high','Record low'])
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.fill_between(range(len(datamax['Date'])), datamax['Data_Value'], datamin['Data_Value'],color='yellow',alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

However, I keep getting the error:

**ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1**

When I modify the code to this:

```
datamax['datamax'] = datamax2015['Data_Value']
datamin['datamin'] = datamin2015['Data_Value']
datamax['breakup'] = datamax[datamax['datamax']>datamax['Data_Value']]
datamin['breakdown'] = datamin[datamin['datamin']<datamin['Data_Value']]

ax = plt.gca()
datamax.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value',color='red',ax=ax)
datamin.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Data_Value', color='blue',ax=ax)

plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees C)",color='navy')
plt.xlabel("Date",color='navy',labelpad=15)
plt.title('Record high and low temperatures by day (2005-2014)', alpha=1.0,color='brown',y=1.08)
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.35),
          fancybox=False,labels=['Record high','Record low'])
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.fill_between(range(len(datamax['Date'])), datamax['Data_Value'], datamin['Data_Value'],color='yellow',alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

The code works, and gives me the output:

[image]

Could anybody let me know what I'm doing wrong?

This line is giving me the error: `datamax['breakup'] = datamax[datamax['datamax']>datamax['Data_Value']]`

Comment: Kindly enlighten people which line is giving the error. Also, in the first code, where is `breakup` and `breakdown` defined?

Comment: @Sheldore have edited above, breakup and breakdown are the names of the new columns in the dataframe datamax and datamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the whole of the dataframe and assigning it to a single column. I think you need the following condition

```
datamax['breakup'] = datamax['datamax'][datamax['datamax']>datamax['Data_Value']]
datamin['breakdown'] = datamin['datamin'][datamin['datamin']<datamin['Data_Value']]
```